# Редактирование ячеек в WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, c#

Задался таким вопросом. Хочу реализовать редактирование ячеек в WPF DataGrid по аналогии с Excel.

Итак, мои мысли.

1. Переопределить ctrl+c && ctrl+v.
2. Отключить возможность удаления строк для пользователя и переопределить кнопку Delete, чтобы можно было очищать (приводить к стандартным значениям) значения ячеек. Но сразу возникает такой вопрос: как реализовать так, чтобы пользователь смог и удалять строки и редактировать (удалять) значения нескольких выбранных ячеек?

Подскажите, правильно ли я мыслю или есть какое-нибудь готовое более изящное решение?

Comment: Взгляните здесь. [DataGrid: Commonly Requested Features](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tips%20%26%20Tricks). Возможно, что-то из этого пригодиться.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне можно сделать так, как вы планируете. Если вы перекроете Del, то для удаления строки потребуется либо определить дополнительную горячую клавишу, например, Ctrl+Del, либо добавить пункт в меню (контекстное или нет).

Еще есть платные Excel-подобные компоненты, вроде [xceed](http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Demo.html), стоит ли DataGrid менять на них, это вопрос.